# Color map based on dataframe with countries' counts values

Tags: python, plotly

I have a dataframe called country which contains country_code and frequency counts for countries.

|  | country_code | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | US | 17600 |
| 1 | CN | 8572 |
| 2 | KR | 1121 |
| 3 | JP | 299 |
| 4 | DE | 199 |

I wrote a code to plot distribution of countries on a world map:

```
import plotly.express as px

np.random.seed(12)
gapminder = country
gapminder['counts'] = np.random.uniform(low=100000, high=200000, size=len(gapminder)).tolist()

fig = px.choropleth(gapminder, locations="country_code",
                    color="frequency", 
                    hover_name="country_code",
                    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Blues)

fig.show()
```

The result I got:

[Output data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn2aD.png)

Something is wrong with the code, I cannot find the reason why the distribution is not shown on the map at all. Could you please help me to correct it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choroplethmap in plotly needs to specify in which format the country name data is represented.

> locationmode: str
> One of 'ISO-3', 'USA-states', or 'country names' Determines the set of
> locations used to match entries in `locations` to regions on the map.

The country name column is a two-letter abbreviation, so it needs to be converted to a three-letter abbreviation. I had to correct it manually because I had a small number of data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
 country_code frequency
0 USA 17600
1 CHN 8572
2 KOR 1121
3 JPN 299
4 DNK 199
'''

country = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

import plotly.express as px

np.random.seed(12)
gapminder = country
gapminder['counts'] = np.random.uniform(low=100000, high=200000, size=len(gapminder)).tolist()

fig = px.choropleth(gapminder, locations="country_code",
                    locationmode='ISO-3',
                    color="frequency", 
                    hover_name="country_code",
                    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Blues)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept it as the correct answer. Click on the check mark under the lower triangle.